# How to return the model on success in Backbone fetch?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, backbone.js

I want to implement the current_user for backbone. 
I do this via sending a request to app.com/current_user.json

The async part of fetch does not seem to work

```
class App.Models.CurrentUser extends Backbone.Model
  url: '/current'
  defaults: 
    "created_at":"never",
    "email":"new",
    "id": "0",
    "updated_at":"always"

  current_user:() =>
    @fetch(
      succes:(response,status) =>
        console.log(status)
        return status
        )
```

Console log prints out exactly what I am trying to return, however the function itself returns an object with responseText as json that I want to get from this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its cause it just returns the model and the server response. This is the part from the backbone source that handles the response on [`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-98)

```
  var success = options.success;
  options.success = function(resp, status, xhr) {
    if (!model.set(model.parse(resp, xhr), options)) return false;
    if (success) success(model, resp);
  };
```

So if you wanna have the model returned, just use the first parameter passed into your success method.

```
current_user:() =>
    @fetch(
      succes:(model,response) =>
        console.log(model)
        return model
        )
```

Comment: Sorry just misread your question. You get the model as the first parameter in your success method.

Comment: hmm I still get this: user = new App.Models.CurrentUser(); a = user.current_user(); a is an object (with response text etc..).?

Comment: This cant work in cause of the async nature of `fetch`. You cant set an variable to the result of an async call just by assigning them the function that makes the call.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you could do:

```
current_user:() =>
  @fetch async: false
  @
```

Note that, in doing so you are telling fetch to not be asynchronous. That means everything else after the fetch will only be processed when the fetching is complete.